# Trying to bind two datetimes together in vue so that one dynamically updates the other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to the values of lease_end to be exactly 364 days less than lease_start when the page is populated or the date is manually changed.

Is this something I need a listener for? I've tried a v-on:change but nothing seemed to work. Not quite sure what is missing here.

I've included the implementation of datetime.

```
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Lease Start <span class="note">4</span></label>
      <datetime type="date"
                v-model="document.lease_start"
                value-zone="America/New_York"
                zone="America/New_York"
                :format="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}"
                :phrases="{ok: 'OK', cancel: 'Cancel'}"
                :minute-step="15"
                use12-hour
                auto
                input-class="form-control"
      >
      </datetime>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Lease End <span class="note">4</span></label>
      <datetime type="date"
                v-model="document.lease_end"
                value-zone="America/New_York"
                zone="America/New_York"
                :format="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}"
                :phrases="{ok: 'OK', cancel: 'Cancel'}"
                :minute-step="15"
                use12-hour
                auto
                input-class="form-control"
      >
      </datetime>
    </div>
  </div>

data() {
  return {
    now: new Date().toISOString(),
    document: {
      lease_start: '',
      lease_end: '',
    }
  }
},

    this.document.lease_start = DateTime.local();
    this.document.lease_end = this.document.lease_start;

methods: {
  leaseEndDate() {
    if(this.document.lease_end) {
      this.$emit(this.document.lease_end = DateTime.local().plus({years:1}).minus({days:1}));
    }
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.leaseEndDate();
},

<template>
  <span>{{datetimeLabel}}</span>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
export default {
  props: [
    'value',
    'tz',
    'empty'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      datetimeLabel: '',
      datetimeValue: '',
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mma',
      timezone: 'America/New_York',
      emptyValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatDatetime: function(event) {
      if(!!this.empty) this.emptyValue = '';
      if(this.value == "" || !this.value) {
        this.datetimeLabel = this.emptyValue;
      }else{
        this.datetimeValue = this.value.replace('T',' ').replace('Z','').replace('z','');
        this.timezone = (this.tz === undefined ? 'America/New_York' : this.tz);
        this.format = (this.format === undefined ? 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mma' : this.format);
        if(this.timezone != 'America/New_York') {
          this.format += ' z';
        }
        if(this.datetimeValue.length == 10) this.datetimeValue = datetimeValue.value + ' 00:00:00';
        this.datetimeLabel = moment(this.datetimeValue+'Z').tz(this.timezone).format(this.format);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
      this.formatDatetime();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.formatDatetime();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Comment: Might be caused by the `v-model` implementation in the `datetime` component. Can you show that code in the question?

Comment: @tony19 I have it at the top

Comment: @tony19 Just added the datetime.vue to the bottom of the code. I'm guessing this is what you were requesting?

Comment: `datetime` looks like a read-only component, in which case `v-model` would not update its variable. It effectively only sets the `value` prop of `datetime`.

Comment: Is there a way to override this? An element I could change in the input variable?

Comment: That's all of it. Normally it's just updated off the calendar and saved on the view. The formatting being done with Luxon.

Comment: The first sentence in the question indicates the date can be "manually changed". How does that change occur?

Comment: Ah, pardon me. I mean that when I choose the date from the datepicker calendar on lease_start that it should update the lease_end to exactly 364 days after the date chosen for lease_start @tony19

I've tried using a method and a computed property, but nothing gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `computed` is for: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

```js
data() {
  return {
    now: new Date().toISOString(),
    document: {
      lease_start: ''
    }
  }
},

computed: {
  lease_end() {
    return this.document.lease_start // - 364 days
  }
}
```

then use like `this.lease_end`

Comment: I tried this exact thing (used yours as well) but it still doesn't update when I change the date value of lease_start.

Comment: Can you try it with flat data? Change it from `this.document.lease_start` to `this.lease_start`

Comment: Still leaves me with an unchanged property, unfortunately. A computer property written your way should work.